# maven: More intelligent way to determine unnecessary dependencies?

Tags: maven

To me, `maven` has been great for managing dependencies between jar files.  But
there is still one thing that bugs me -- regarding unnecessary dependencies,

For example, we may have `pom.xml` that says Artifact A depends on B, and B depends on C.  But there are extra information (via email, forum, etc) that tells us that A does not really use C.  An example of that would be this

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.hive:hive-exec:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- ...
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.calcite:calcite-core:jar:1.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ...
[INFO] |  |  \- org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:jar:5.1.5-jhyde:compile
```

The author of C (in this example `org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm`) would
tell me (via an Internet forum) that ([link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-605)):

> Note that when Hive uses Calcite it doesn't use
>   pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm (either at compile time or at run time),
>   so you can safely exclude that dependency.

I know how to exclude the dependency, and my question here is whether there
a more intelligent way to determine that a dependency is not really
needed? Or we really rely on the `pom.xml` to be very accurate in terms of
their dependencies?

My another example is this: I see this dependency:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.8:system
```

I suspect that the dependency on `jdk.tools` is not 
really needed.  But how do I know for sure?  Is there
a better way than trial and error or contacting the developers?

Comment: I wouldn't mess with it unless you have a dependency conflict.lots of libraries tend to load classes in runtime via a string name. even if you wrote a tool to load all classes at runtime to discover which jars are not used, this might not be feasible to figure out. tools.jar is a good example, maybe hadoop uses the compiler api and that would make the task even more complicated. but you can see that the dependency is loaded from system, from jdk lib directory.